# Make placeholder dimensions that were previously dynamic for existing models static

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorrt

I trained a tensorflow model for object detection with the input as a placeholder with the dimension [1,None,None,3] since my training images have various sizes. I then converted the frozen graph (.pb file) to a tensorRT graph for faster inference, but tensorRT gave me the warning that the input tensor has unknown non-batch dimension and thus the node would fall back to TF. The error message is:

```
2019-05-22 08:59:56.628216: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3710] Validation failed for TensorRTInputPH_0 and input slot 0: Input tensor with shape [1,?,?,3] has an unknown non-batch dimension at dim 1
2019-05-22 08:59:56.628262: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:1021] TensorRT node TRTEngineOp_0 added for segment 0 consisting of 160 nodes failed: Invalid argument: Validation failed for TensorRTInputPH_0 and input slot 0: Input tensor with shape [1,?,?,3] has an unknown non-batch dimension at dim 1. Fallback to TF...
```

I know I can set the is_dynamic_op to True in trt.create_inference_graph, but this increases the runtime. I want to use this model for the inference of a video, in which all frames have the same height and width. Is there a way to fix the input placeholder dimensions to static values without having to re-train the model? My input tensor can be accessed by get_tensor_by_name

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the static mode.

The default operating mode of TF-TRT is called static mode, and it is active whenever the parameter `is_dynamic_op` is set to False. In static mode, it is required that all shapes in the model are fully defined (dimensions cannot be None or -1). When the argument is_dynamic_op is set to True, TF-TRT will operate in dynamic mode. In dynamic mode, the TF-TRT API (create_inference_graph in TF <= 1.13) returns a modified graph, but no TensorRT engines are created at this time. Instead, the TensorRT engines are created during runtime when you send an input to the graph.

The main advantage of dynamic mode is that it allows you to have unknown shapes in your model, despite the fact that TensorRT requires all shapes to be fully defined. In this mode, TF-TRT creates a new TensorRT engine for each unique input shape that is supplied to the model.